# How to return Respone from Jersey REST api method which has listners inside

Tags: java, rest, firebase, jersey, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create REST apis to perform write operations using [Firebase Server SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) and Jersey.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1. [Initializing Firebase SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup#initialize_the_sdk)
2. [Getting idToken from Client and Validating idToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/server/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_sdk)
3. Performing some write operations on few Firebase nodes
4. Sending api Response

I want to return Response only if Firebase write operation succeeds or fails.
That happens inside of Firebase Listeners. However, I try to return value from Listeners, I get error becuase Firebase listeners have void return type.

How can I return response from the listener?

Here is my code.

**MyEndpoint.java**

```
@Path("/restapi")
//BaseEndpoint does Authentication operations
public class MyEndpoint extends BaseEndpoint {

    public void Authenticate(String token, AuthenticationListener authenticationResultListener) {
        super.Authenticate(token, authenticationResultListener);
    }

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response createCommunity(@FormParam("idToken") String idToken) {
        Authenticate(idToken, new AuthenticationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationSuccess() {
                // The app only has access as defined in the Security Rules
                DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/mysamplenode");
                ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        String res = dataSnapshot.getKey();
                        //I will do some write operations on Firebase here
                        //If they complete successfuly only then I want to return api response
                        return Response.status(200).entity().build();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
                        System.out.println("DatabaseError-------------" + arg0);
                        return Response.status(500).entity("DatabaseError").build();
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onAuthenticationFailure() {
                return Response.status(403).entity("Forbidden").build();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**BaseEndpoint.java**

```
    public class BaseEndpoint {

    public static String uid;

    public void Authenticate(String token, AuthenticationListener authenticationResultListener) {
        // idToken comes from the client app
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Exception arg0) {
                System.out.println("Uid exp= " + arg0);
                authenticationResultListener.onAuthenticationFailure();
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
                uid = decodedToken.getUid();
                System.out.println("Uid= " + uid);
                authenticationResultListener.onAuthenticationSuccess();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm guessing the Firebase SDK is asynchronous in nature. In which case, if you're using Jersey 2.x, you can use the [asynchronous server support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e10208). You can just call `AsyncResponse.resume(Response)` in your callbacks. For example

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void createCommunity(@FormParam("idToken") String idToken,
                                @Suspended final AsyncResponse response) {
    Authenticate(idToken, new AuthenticationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess() {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference("/mysamplenode");
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String res = dataSnapshot.getKey();                        
                    response.resume(Response.status(200).entity().build());
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
                    response.resume(Response.status(500).entity("DatabaseError").build());
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure() {
            response.resume(Response.status(403).entity("Forbidden").build());
        }
    });
}
```

If you're using Jersey 1.x, there's not really an async option. You just need to block flow with a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), assign a local `Response` in the callbacks, and count down.

```
@POST
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void createCommunity(@FormParam("idToken") String idToken) {
    Response response;
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    Authenticate(idToken, new AuthenticationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess() {
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReference("/mysamplenode");
            ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String res = dataSnapshot.getKey();                        
                    response = Response.status(200).entity().build();
                    latch.countDown();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError arg0) {
                    response = Response.status(500).entity("DatabaseError").build();
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            });
        }
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationFailure() {
            response = Response.status(403).entity("Forbidden").build();
            latch.countDown();
        }
    });
    latch.await();
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks promising, I am using following dependency. What do I have to change to use Jersey. 2.X?
 `<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
   <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
   <version>1.9</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: It not as simple as just changing dependencies. You still need some configuration. If you have no experience with Jersey 2, you should check out this [getting started guide](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-started-with-jersey-2.html)

Comment: I have setup Jersey2.23.1 now. But I am getting error for Async call. Here is the error `WARNING: Attempt to put servlet request into asynchronous mode has failed. Please check your servlet configuration - all Servlet instances and Servlet filters involved in the request processing must explicitly declare support for asynchronous request processing.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations.` 
Spent lot of time finding out the solution,none of them worked.

Comment: Change the `jersey-container-servlet-core` to `jersey-container-servlet`. Then set `<async-supported>true</asyn-supported>` inside the Jersey servlet definition in the web.xml

Comment: You may also need to change the web.xml schema version. For that see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36741296/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late in answering this question, but after trying the Firebase server SDK out I found that you can create a Task available in the SDK to wait for a response synchronously. The snippet below might help you out:

```
public class BaseEndpoint {

    public static String uid;

    public void Authenticate(String token, AuthenticationListener authenticationResultListener) {
        // idToken comes from the client app
        FirebaseToken firebaseToken = null;
        try {
            Task<FirebaseToken> authTask = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token);
            Tasks.await(authTask);
            firebaseToken = authTask.getResult();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            authenticationResultListener.onAuthenticationFailure();
        }
        uid = firebaseToken.getUid();
        System.out.println("Uid= " + uid);
        authenticationResultListener.onAuthenticationSuccess();
    }
}
```