# Can't get rid of "IllegalStateException: A filter or servlet of the current chain does not support asynchronous operations" exception using Jersey SSE

Tags: java, rest, jersey, server-sent-events

I'm trying to configure a basic broadcast server using server-sent events with Jersey. I used the example code included in the official documentation:

```
public class Broadcast {


@Singleton
@Path("broadcasting")
public static class BroadcasterResource {

    private SseBroadcaster broadcaster = new SseBroadcaster();

    /**
     * Server receives a message and broadcasts to its suscribers 
     * @param message
     * @return 
     */
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String broadcastMessage(String message) {
        OutboundEvent.Builder eventBuilder = new OutboundEvent.Builder();
        OutboundEvent event = eventBuilder.name("message")
            .mediaType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE)
            .data(String.class, message)
            .build();

        broadcaster.broadcast(event);

        return "Message '" + message + "' has been broadcast.";
    }

    /**
     * Suscribes the client to the broadcaster
     * @return 
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(SseFeature.SERVER_SENT_EVENTS)
    public EventOutput listenToBroadcast() {
        final EventOutput eventOutput = new EventOutput();
        this.broadcaster.add(eventOutput);
        return eventOutput;
    }
}
}
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="TestSSE" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>TestSSE</display-name>        
    <servlet>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>             
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.mycompany.testsse.sse</param-value>
        </init-param>       
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>                
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And pom.xml:

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestSSE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>TestSSE</name>

    <properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to implement this webservice directly into my app in development, and as I was unable to make it work, I created this basic maven web application with nothing else than the code showed above, in order to try to isolate the error.

The application works as expectly, but always throws this exception when receive the GET request (not the POST). Notice that the `<async-supported>` tag is added to the servlet.

I'm using Java EE 7 and Tomcat 8.0.27.0

Comment: What happens if you change `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"` to `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_3_0.xsd"` - notice the 3_0. If that doesn't work (looks like an old namespace), try [this](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/)

Comment: [for explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36740624/2587435)

Comment: As you said, it seems to be some problem with the namespace, but I can't find out what yet. I think I might have some trouble with invalid/old xsd files in cache. Changing to `3_0.xsd` throw this error: `TargetNamespace.1: Expecting namespace 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee', but the target namespace of the schema document is 'http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee'`

Comment: And changing the `j2ee` to `javaee` in the url, I get `cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'web-app'`

Comment: Changing the web-app tag to `<web-app id="TestSSE" version="3.0" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">` and placing the `async-supported` tag after the `load-on-startup` remove the error at XML validation. Unfortunately, exception is still being throwed at GET requests.

Comment: You could just get rid the web.xml and just use a `ResourceConfig` subclass annotated with `@ApplicationPath("/v2/*")`. You don't need to do anything else. Your class will automatically be picked up. You can call `packages` inside your constructor to package scan just like your init-param

Comment: Didn't work either, exception continues